# Reflection of a curve(advanced)

Tags: geometry

x=logy (base 10) is the reflection of y=logx (base 10) about the line whose equation is?

An answer with a detailed approach is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

By the way, the answer is y=x

Comment: Try graphing the functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two given functions, $x= \log y$ and $y= \log x$, or more generally, $x= f(y)$ and $y= f(x)$,  just swap $(x, y)$ with $(y, x)$.  The line of "reflection" if any, must be the perpendicular bisector of every line segment from $(x, y)$ with $(y, x)$.

In particular, the line from  $(x_0, y_0)$ to $(y_0, x_0)$ has slope $\dfrac{x_0- y_0}{y_0- x_0}= -1$.  Any line perpendicular to that must have slope 1.  The line segement from $(x_0, y_0)$ to $(y_0, x_0)$ has midpoint $(\frac{x_0+ y_0}{2}, \frac{y_0+ x_0}{2})$.  So the perpendicular bisector of that line segment is $y= 1\left(x- \frac{x_0+ y_0}{2}\right)+ \frac{x_0+ y_0}{2}$ which is simply $y= x$.  Notice that this does NOT depend upon the specific point $(x_0, y_0)$.

Comment: User247327. I found your answer helpful.Thank you....

Answer (score 0):

If you have an equation in terms of $x$ and $y$, and then switch the position of the $y$ and $x$, your new equation is known as an inverse function. Inverse functions are always reflected about the line $y=x$.

By the way, $ x = \log(y) $ is also $ y = 10^x $